# How can I translate the calendar of moodle?

Tags: moodle

Indeed as seen in the title I have a translation problem.
You have two examples here:

1. [Date is in English 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnT6C.png)
2. [Date is in English 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S21b0.png)

On the forums, people say the problem is with the server locales 
[Locale of the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBXbC.png)

On the admin page, I have this configuration: 
[Admin config lanuge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjDa7.png)
[Locale site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqUSo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the locales on the server side for the correct dates.

eg: To install the French locale on Ubuntu

```
sudo locale-gen fr_FR
sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8 

// Then update the table
sudo update-locale 

// And restart apache for the changes to take affect.
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then test the locales are working via Site admin > Localisation > Locale compatibility check

Or direct to `/admin/tool/langimport/localecheck.php`

See here for other operating systems

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales

Comment: Thank you for your reply
On my server with the command `date` I have the correct date format.
I don't have the page you gave me or the links in the menu.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, the local compatibility check is a feature in Totara 12, its not in Moodle. To check if the locale is correct, select a different language in Moodle then check the date output for days of the week and month names.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, sorry ... Are you talking about the site's locales? or the default language?

Comment: Install the locales as above on the * server *, then go into Moodle, change/select the language which should display the date in the correct language

Comment: Nothing to do after installing the locale I may change the language to another and put it back does not change anything.
I changed the language of the site locale
The language of the site.
But nothing has changed